# How to install/update wayland without building it?

Tags: software-installation, 18.04, wayland

I want to install the newest version of `wayland` display server, because the new `Ubuntu 18.04` comes with old `wayland-protocols/bionic,bionic 1.13-1` and the mouse is lagging and the animations are laggy.

So the newest releases according to this link are `v1.16.0`, which I want to give a try: https://wayland.freedesktop.org/releases.html

But there is no instruction on how to install these files. There is an `install-sh` file, which I can't run and the `readme` file tells me to go to `gitlab` and `clone` and `make` wayland. What do I need these release files then for if they tell me to go to gitlab and clone and make. Did I get something wrong?

Comment: I am not sure, but way wayland is a protocol as far as I know

Answer (score 2):

Wayland is actually one of the easiest softwares to build from source since it has very few dependencies.

As per the README, you'll need libffi, and if you start building, you'll also hear it ask for libxml2.

```
# apt-get install --no-install-recommends libffi-dev libxml2-dev
```

Then, just build and install as usual. Instead of `make install`, you can try `checkinstall` for ease of uninstall at a later date.

```
./autogen.sh #(old versions use ./configure)
sudo checkinstall #(or use make install)
```

That's everything. Maybe restart your compositor so it'll take advantage of the new libraries.

---

> What do I need these release files then for if they tell me to go to gitlab and clone and make.

The "release" is a frozen source archive. The GitLab business in the README is an oversight because someone forgot to change the instructions for the tarball.

---

ALT: cosmic has `wayland-protocols` v1.16 in the repos. If you don't mind trying out unreleased software, you can perform a full system upgrade. (Note that downgrading is not supported, so make backups first.)

Comment: He specifically asked for "without building it" but I agree that this is somewhat better as an answer if the intended end-result is to have 1.16.

Comment: Doing this: `$ git clone https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/wayland/wayland
    $ cd wayland
    $ ./autogen.sh --prefix=/opt/wayland
    $ make` gives me an error: `make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.`

Comment: thank you. What would you suggest as an install path? `--prefix=?`

Comment: @sunwarr10r Ubuntu 22 Desktop - `--prefix=/usr/`

Answer (score 0):

Wayland provides a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~wayland.admin/+archive/ubuntu/daily-builds) that is updated daily.

To install it:

```
ppa-purge ppa:wayland.admin/daily-builds
apt-add-repository ppa:wayland.admin/daily-builds
apt-get update
```

And you install Weston (Wayland compositor) with...

```
sudo apt-get install weston
```

This PPA comes with a warning:

> IMPORTANT: This is for experimentation/testing only, not for production use. Before upgrading your system to a new Ubuntu release you should probably run `ppa-purge ppa:wayland.admin/daily-builds` first.

Comment: Can I get the newest `STABLE` version via the `ppa`?

Comment: That PPA has 1.14 as the latest.  1.13 is the latest stable (that would be this PPA https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/wayland ). There is no 1.16 yet. Mind that I include "without building" from your title in my answer as 1.16 you need to compile/build so that does not fit into the question.

Comment: I get an error on `sudo ppa-purge ppa:wayland.admin/daily-builds` which looks like this: `E: The repository 'http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/dists bionic-dell Release' does not have a Release file.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/wayland.admin/daily-builds/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.`